# How to write this matrix equation in latex in the center position?

Tags: pdftex, matrices

I want to write something like in the images by using

[image]

I also want to place a subscript in the right bottom part of the very right matrices. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You should seek an introductory book on LaTeX and how to do things in math mode, in particular.   See [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
m\\k
\end{pmatrix}
= X
\begin{pmatrix}
t\\u
\end{pmatrix}
_r
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible, depending on your notation, that you would prefer the look of `\mathbf{X}` in lieu of `X`.

[image]

And Bernard rightly suggests that the subscript could be tucked in closer to the vector, by employing the subscript as `_{\mkern-5mu r}` rather than simply as `_r`.

[image]

**By popular demand**, the alternative with `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[ \parenVectorstack{m k}= X \parenVectorstack{t u}_r \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, one could have done this with `stackengine.`   You're slacking off.....

Comment: @JPi You have only yourself to blame for my edit.

Comment: What if I want to use equation environment?

Comment: Don't you think the index would look nicer using `_{\!r}` (or even `_{\mkern-5mu r}`, depending on the size of the parentheses?

Comment: @DamianDulkawie  The use of `\[...\]` produces an unnumbered equation.  For numbering, it may be, without any other changes, replaced with `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`.